# SQL Syntax Issue for Wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm getting an error that my syntax is wrong, and I may have failed to escape something... anyone have any thoughts?

```
    UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value`= 
    'a:2{i:0\;s:10:\"subscriber\"\;i:1;s:13:\"administrator\"\;}' WHERE 
    `meta_key` = "__wpdm_access"
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using double quotes for `WHERE` condition? Have you tried using `WHERE \`meta_key\` = '__wpdm_access'`? What does the error say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an issue with putting quotes around table and column names.

Try this:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value= 'a:2{i:0\;s:10:\"subscriber\"\;i:1;s:13:\"administrator\"\;}' 
WHERE meta_key = '__wpdm_access'
```